# How to summarise unique categorical variable for duplicate rows

Tags: r

| Applicant | Age | Date (MM/YY) | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 10 | 10/21 | Fail |
| Alex | 10 | 11/21 | Pass |
| Bryan | 21 | 10/21 | Fail |
| Howard | 30 | 11/21 | Pass |

So essentially I am playing with an exam database which has all exam attempts recorded- therefore some applicants who failed it, and decided to re-take it are repeated twice.

I have two main goals from this, (a) Summarise all applicants by Age/other demographics not included here - I have been able to do this by removing the duplicates and than summarising the new datasets

However, **I also want to be able to show** a flow of how many unique applicants took the exam once, or more than once and what the outcomes were. I.e 1 applicant- took it twice, passed on second/ 2 applicants took it once, half passed.

Comment: Can be done in multiple ways, how would you like your final dataframe to look like?

Comment: Thanks for your reply James, Essentally - I have already deleted duplicates, so only unique applicants are shown. If I can than create a few more descriptive colums, perhaps one with 'Number of exam attempts', ' Pass-Yes/No'

Comment: I agree with Just James above, this can be done is many ways, all depends on what the final dataframe you want in the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do with the [{tidyverse}](https://www.tidyverse.org/) packages. To visualize the summarized data, one option is a histogram with color by the final outcome. It's not very interesting with 3 data points, but with a larger dataset might be a good way to look at it.

Also this assumes that `Applicant` and `Age` are sufficient to uniquely identify each person. If not, you will need to do something else to uniquely identify them.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- data.frame(
  Applicant = c("Alex", "Alex", "Bryan", "Howard"),
  Age = c(10, 10, 21, 30),
  Date = c("10/21", "11/21", "10/21", "11/21"),
  Result = c("Fail", "Pass", "Fail", "Pass")
)

e <- d %>% 
  group_by(Applicant, Age) %>% 
  summarize(attempts = n(), 
         final_result = if_else(any(str_detect(Result, "Pass")), "Pass", "Fail"),
         .groups = "drop")

e
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   Applicant   Age attempts final_result
#>   <chr>     <dbl>    <int> <chr>       
#> 1 Alex         10        2 Pass        
#> 2 Bryan        21        1 Fail        
#> 3 Howard       30        1 Pass

# visualize with histogram by final outcome
e %>% 
  ggplot(aes(attempts, fill = final_result)) +
  geom_histogram(position = "dodge", binwidth = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>